# To Show catalog price rule id applied on products in order API response

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, catalog-rules, sales-order-item

I have created a custom field named **catalog_price_rule_id** in **sales_order_item**. Now i need to get the catalog price rule applied on that orderitem; then i need to store that into the custom field and finally I will have to expose that custom field in the order API response.